# Sorting table tbody and its rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table that contains multiple `tbody` and I would like to make the `tbody` and its rows sortable.

PS: When I was trying to compose this question, I tried to create a fiddle for this to explain my problem, but I think I solved it on my own.

#### [Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johngarcia25/b9wydx6q/10/)

Comment: So. Either delete the question or answer the question yourself. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't Go hard with manual coding every time use jquery data Table for showing rows in table and for sorting on column basis

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to compose this question, I tried to create a fiddle for this to explain my problem, but I think I solved it on my own.

```
$("#mytable").sortable({
items: "> tbody, tr:not(.item)",
beforeStop: function( event, ui ) {        
    var $con = $(ui.placeholder);
    if($(ui.item).data('parent') !== $con.parent().data("name")) {
        return false;
    }
},
placeholder : "highlightPlaceHolder"
```

});

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johngarcia25/b9wydx6q/10/)